# Sitecore IP Geolocation only works on CM, NOT CD

Tags: configuration, geo-location

So I am having an issue with my Geolocation on my CD server, it only comes back with US regardless if trying it from India, Australia or anywhere. CM comes back with the correct country code. I have read through the ticket from 2018 and tried to do everything on that thread as well as I have updated what the sitecore docs have:

- Analytics.PerformLookup = true
- subscribed to the service we are using
- Sucuri as our firewall and load balancer, I allowed both of the
  service urls geoIp-ces.cloud.sitecore.net and
  Discovery-ces.cloud.sitecore.net on sucuri. We have an app gateway on
  azure that I havent set up anything for.
- Analytics.ForwardedRequestHttpHeader = X-Forwarded-For

Is there anything else that is not setup correctly that I am missing or where I can find more settings that need updated? Like I said seems like the service is running since I get "US" back for everything but that is the broken part as well. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Do you have any CDN configured for CD server like azure front door, Akamai etc. ?

Comment: No just Sucuri and the app appgateway on azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tracked the issue done to our Application gateway and that is the IP getting passed to the service. The answers above helped a lot with tracking this down so I appreciate the help.

If anyone has any experience with this issue of allowing the IP through please reach out, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Enable Sitecore Geolocation Service API:** First, you need to raise a request to Sitecore to activate the Sitecore IP Geolocation service. For the same, you can refer to Sitecore Documents. See the document: [Set up Sitecore IP Geolocation](https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/101/sitecore-experience-manager/set-up-sitecore-ip-geolocation.html)

Now you need to make sure that `XB and Analytics tracker` is working fine in your environment.

Get the IP address from the Current Tracker as mentioned below:

```
if (Tracker.IsActive == false)
 {
    Tracker.StartTracking();
 }
return (Tracker.Current?.Interaction?.Ip != null) ?
    new IPAddress(Tracker.Current.Interaction.Ip).ToString() : string.Empty;
```

Once you will find the IP address of the user you can fetch the other details of the user. Sitecore provides below methods for this purpose:

1. Sitecore.Analytics.Lookups.LookupManager.GetInformationByIp(…)
2. Sitecore.CES.GeoIp.Core.Lookups.LookupManager.GetWhoIsInformationByIp(...)
3. Sitecore.DependencyInjection.ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<Sitecore.CES.GeoIp.Core.IGeoIpManager>().GetGeoIpData(...)

See blog post for more details: [Sitecore Geolocation Service API](https://himmatsinghdulawat.blogspot.com/2021/09/sitecore-geolocation-api.html)